# как тянуть текст с разных файлов json передавая его в один компонент?

Tags: json, reactjs, компоненты

у меня есть компонет, который используется на многих страницах. Нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я вставляла этот компонет на определенную страницу-был определенный текст, взятый с json,  то есть компонент один, а текст разный.. как это сделать?

Comment: Например запрашивать один и тот же файл `json` с помощь `fetch api`

Answer (score 0):

Переделанный пример из [документации](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html):

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  // Заметка: пустой массив зависимостей [] означает
  // что этот useEffect будет запущен 1 раз
  // похоже на componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("./data/data.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        // Заметка: важно обрабатывать ошибки тут
        // вместо блока catch(), чтобы мы не пропускали
        // исключения из реальных ошибок в компонентах
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name} {item.price}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Так же можно обойтись и без `fetch`, елси не хотите перемещать ваш `json` файл в публичную папку:

```
import data from '../data/data.json';

const loadedData = JSON.stringify(data);
const json = JSON.parse(loadedData);
```